# How do I transfer data from Excel>Python>Microsft Access

Tags: python, excel, ms-access

I have been working on this for days now.  Someone please give any advice that you can.  Here is my current code (it doesn't work, and I know why it doesn't work):

```
import pyodbc

import openpyxl

path = ('C:\\Access_Test.xlsx')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.active
b2 = a2 = sheet['A2']
b2 = sheet['B2']
c2 = sheet['C2']
d2 = sheet['D2']
e2 = sheet['E2']
f2 = sheet['F2']
g2 = sheet['G2']
h2 = sheet['H2']
i2 = sheet['I2']
j2 = sheet['J2']
k2 = sheet['K2']
l2 = sheet['L2']
m2 = sheet['M2']
n2 = sheet['N2']
o2 = sheet['O2']
test2 = (")'")
test =  (a2.value, b2.value, c2.value, d2.value, e2.value, f2.value, g2.value, h2.value, i2.value, j2.value, k2.value, l2.value, m2.value),(test2)  

#Everything to this point is fine.  I can read & print everything from the Excel document (though the formatting is an issue with how the query statements work in pyodbc).




driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *accdb)}'
filepath = 'C:\\Users\\Db_Mngr\\Desktop\\PythonTests\\Microsoft Studio Projects\\HUD Report-2001-Copy For Python.mdb'

#Find data sources
myDataSources = pyodbc.dataSources()
access_driver = myDataSources['MS Access Database']

#This is the full command to open the Access database
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=access_driver, dbq=filepath, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

crsr.execute(str(test))
```

If I use:

```
print:(test)
```

My output looks like this (all data is fake for this test):

```
("'''INSERT INTO Python_Test([Case2], [Last], [First], [Initial Intake], [Intake], [Age], [Gender], [Ethnic], [Race], [DOB], [SSN], [Educ Lvl], [Marital])VALUES", ('Sep00000', 'Test', 'Test', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2020', 1, 'Male', 'A. Hispanic', 'E. White', '01/01/2020', 0, 'High School'), ")'")
```

As you can see, this is about 70% correct for the purpose of pyodbc, but It obviously throws back errors (too many quotation marks at the beginning, quotation mark after "VALUES", the " " after "VALUES".... etc, you get my point).  Is anyone capable of trying to explain how to make this code functional?

Removing the extra quotes at the beginning isn't the biggest issue necessarily, I think I can figure that out; but everything going on after the "VALUES" portion is just a huge mess.

Would appreciate ANY feedback!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `test` is a tuple, right? Is that not the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code guys!

```
import pyodbc

import openpyxl

path = ('C:\\Users\\Db_Mngr\\Desktop\\PythonTests\\Microsoft Studio Projects\\Access_Test.xlsx') #Set the path to the Excel document that you want to transfer data from
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.active


b2 = sheet['B2']
c2 = sheet['C2']
d2 = sheet['D2']
e2 = sheet['E2']
f2 = sheet['F2']
g2 = sheet['G2']
h2 = sheet['H2']
i2 = sheet['I2']
j2 = sheet['J2']
k2 = sheet['K2']
l2 = sheet['L2']
m2 = sheet['M2']
n2 = sheet['N2']
o2 = sheet['O2']

#This is the trouble spot.  If you've ever worked with this stuff you know that the formatting has to be PERFECT.  A single space out of place throws errors. 

startcmmd = "'''INSERT INTO Python_Test([Case2], [Last], [First], [Initial Intake], [Intake], [Age], [Gender], [Ethnic], [Race], [DOB], [SSN], [Educ Lvl], [Marital])VALUES('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')'''".format(b2.value, c2.value, d2.value, e2.value, f2.value, g2.value, h2.value, i2.value, j2.value, k2.value, l2.value, m2.value, n2.value)

#Get connected to your Access document

driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *accdb)}'
filepath = 'C:\\Users\\Db_Mngr\\Desktop\\PythonTests\\Microsoft Studio Projects\\HUD Report-2001-Copy For Python.mdb'


myDataSources = pyodbc.dataSources()
access_driver = myDataSources['MS Access Database']

#set up your cursor    

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=access_driver, dbq=filepath, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

#Now execute!  Don't forget to run this with eval!
crsr.execute(eval(startcmmd))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you just need to properly format a string to be valid SQL query. Try something like this

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO table([Case2], [Last], ...) VALUES ({a2.value}, {b2.value}, ...)"
```

or

```
sql = ''.join(test)
```

Comment: Dude I’m going to try that as soon as I get to work on Monday. If the F command actually does a literal input (I’m still kind of new to Python) you will have made my week.

Comment: So either my inexperience or the functionality with the f string didn't work out, BUT it did point me down the correct path (i'm leaning toward inexperience btw).  I wound up going with the .format approach and it WORKED PERFECTLY.  Will post the working code now.

Comment: Update:  It was my inexperience.  f string & .format obviously basically do the exact same thing.  For whatever reason I understood how to use the .format method a little bit quicker which is why I figured out it's exact formatting a little quicker.  Thanks for the help Lukasz!  You truly did make my week!